# Error with Google Places Address Autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete

Implemented this on our site about a month ago and it was working perfectly. Today, suddenly, I am getting this error on all pages that have the auto complete. I created a blank page with nothing but the example code copy pasted from Google's Docs, and I still get the error. Yet on Google's site, the example works.

The error is:

> ReferenceError: V is not defined
>   ...,function(a,b){V("places_impl",N(this,function(){this.Sa.getDetails(a,b)}))});G....

Here is the code, straight from Google:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initialize() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
  // to geographical location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      { types: ['geocode'] });
  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
  // populate the address fields in the form.
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress();
  });
}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}
// [END region_fillform]

// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
          position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      autocomplete.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(geolocation,
          geolocation));
    });
  }
}
// [END region_geolocation]

    </script>

    <style>
      #locationField, #controls {
        position: relative;
        width: 480px;
      }
      #autocomplete {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 99%;
      }
      .label {
        text-align: right;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 100px;
        color: #303030;
      }
      #address {
        border: 1px solid #000090;
        background-color: #f0f0ff;
        width: 480px;
        padding-right: 2px;
      }
      #address td {
        font-size: 10pt;
      }
      .field {
        width: 99%;
      }
      .slimField {
        width: 80px;
      }
      .wideField {
        width: 200px;
      }
      #locationField {
        height: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="locationField">
      <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
             onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
    </div>

    <table id="address">
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Street address</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">City</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">State</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field"
              id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="label">Zip code</td>
        <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Country</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
              id="country" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

On Google's example page, there is an error relating to a variable "Tk", but it the example still works. Whatever this V is, it is killing all my code. Any help?

Comment: The same thing started happening for me. It was working fine for months until today. Looks like Google has updated the Maps JS which in turn has introduced this bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though you haven't mentioned which browser you are using and whether you use Firebug, here's what worked for me:

Initially, I thought Google updated their Maps JS which introduced this bug. However, after further digging around and testing in other browsers, I finally realised that this issue is caused by Firebug 2.0. Firebug got automatically updated to v2.0 on my computer, thus resulting in the error. Downgrading Firebug resolves the issue.

Comment: Holy crap man, thank you! I've been beating my brains out over this one. Just downgraded to Firebug 1.12.8 and it works again. I didn't realize they automatically updated Firebug. Rude. Supposed to ask me. Hope they fix it soon.